# Rollover shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

Assuming a shell script(commands.sh) with few commands.

I need to write a script which sends the output of commands executed by commands.sh to a file f1.csv
if file size exceeds 1MB then the output flowing should go to  file f2.csv
if the file size exceeds 1 mb again here,the output flowing should go to file f3.csv
if f3.csv exceeds the size 1mb,then the older f1 should be deleted and again new file f1 should be created,
output flowing should be to written to f1. This process should go on .

I can write the crontab file, just the shell script is a bit tricky

I have been experimenting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PREFIX="f"
# Maximum size after which you want a new file in bytes
MAX_SIZE=1048576
LAST_FILE=`ls "$prefix"*.csv | tail -1`
# Check if file exists and if it does not, create it.
if [[ -z "$LAST_FILE" ]]
  then
  LAST_FILE=$PREFIX"1.csv"
  touch $LAST_FILE
fi
LAST_FILE_NO=`echo $LAST_FILE | sed s/$PREFIX/''/ | sed s/.csv/''/`
LAST_FILE_SIZE=`stat -c %s $LAST_FILE`


if [ `stat -c %s $LAST_FILE` -lt 200 ]
  then
     `/bin/sh ./sam.sh >> $LAST_FILE`
  else
    UPCOMING_FILE_NO=$((LAST_FILE_NO+1))
    `/bin/sh ./sam.sh >> $PREFIX$UPCOMING_FILE_NO.csv`
fi
```

help is appreciated guys.

EDIT: Have got the secondary shell script to work too...
Now if anyone could help me with resetting after 3 files are done and starting from f1.

thanks

Comment: How about using `logrotate`?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd be better off using logrotate, depending on how your script is running. If you are running 'commands.sh' on a cron, you can have logrotate rotate out the logs. There is a good guide on logrotate here:
http://linuxers.org/howto/howto-use-logrotate-manage-log-files

If your commands.sh isn't going to be on a cron, meaning it's not a regular time interval that triggers it, you could manually set up a log rotation at the beginning of your script. I once had to do something similar. I found this guide really useful:

http://wazem.blogspot.com/2013/11/simple-bash-log-rotate-function.html

Comment: Hi but im not allowed to use logrotate. Can we have a shell script solution ?

Comment: That second link I provided is a way to implement your own log rotation at the beginning of your script. I would say use that. When your script runs, the first code section should be a log rotation, THEN it does the normal work your script is supposed to do. That way the logs are rotated everytime you run the script.